# why i'm getting array of undefined objects, when i'm using Subscribed data into component.html Angular 6/8?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, multi-select

when subscribing data from API and tried to use it in a ng-multiselect-dropdown. but ng-multiselect-dropdown only containing undefined objects as list of options. when i'm print it in console immediately after subscribing it printing expected values.

**Output:**
[image: Output]

**Console:**
[image: Output]

**component.Html**

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown 
    [placeholder]="'custom placeholder'" 
    [data]="arr" 
    [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
    [settings]="dropdownSettings" 
    (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" 
    (onSelectAll)="onSelectAll($event)">
  </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

**component.ts**

```
constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
    const things = this.db.collection('games').valueChanges();
    things.subscribe(data => {
      this.arr = data;
      console.log(this.arr);
    })
  }
```

[Stackblitz URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-firedemo)

Comment: do you have stackblitz to reproduce this scenario?

Comment: What is selectedItems here used in ngModel ? Also can you paste the complete code of component here ? The values printed are different as compared to 1st one. For example item_id instead of id. I guess the data is getting changed somehow in your component.

Comment: I'll post a stackblitz link

Comment: provide a stackblitz link please

Comment: @HirasHaris stackblitz url added

Comment: @ng-suhas please check the stackblitz url

Comment: @GokulSundaramoorthy Thanks for the stackblitz. I have given my solution hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mention the `idField` and `textField` properly in the dropdown Settings.

```
this.dropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      idField: "id", //changed itemId to id
      textField: "name",// changed itemName to name
      selectAllText: "Select All",
      unSelectAllText: "UnSelect All",
      itemsShowLimit: 3,
      allowSearchFilter: true
    };
```

Because in your API it returns object with these aatributes.

[image]

Working Link => https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-firedemo-zdc3zk

Hope it helps!

Comment: @GokulSundaramoorthy Welcome bro. Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the code to below mentioned one:

```
constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
    const things = this.db.collection('games').valueChanges();
    things.subscribe((data) => this.arr = data;)
  }
```